# upload image in form submit with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have form submited with Ajax I can't upload image in this submit

```
<form id="forms-items" name="forms-items" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="uploadBtn" name="uploadimg" type="file" class="upload" />
</form
```

in submit code

```
if($_FILES['uploadimg']['size']>0)
{
    $ftype=$_FILES["uploadimg"]["type"];
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadimg']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
    {
        $default=1;
        $mesg="File Uploaded Successfully";
    }
    else
        $mesg="File Uploading Failed!!";
    else
        $mesg="Please Select A File";
```

The output: `Please Select A File`

**JavaScript code**

```
$("#forms-items").submit(function()
{   
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/submitform.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#forms-items").serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Can you paste your js code

Comment: what is your $target_path? and you have created 2 else...you mean if, else if and else?

Comment: Can you paste the whole of your PHP code? It looks as though a portion is cut out of this post due to the muddled if, if, else, else

Comment: You are missing a `{`. Is that a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: there is no syntax error the problem is this code can't find the file which I want to upload

Comment: There is a syntax error. You cannot have two `else` blocks for one `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it’s easiest to use the [`FormData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) class:

So now you have a FormData object, ready to be sent along with the XMLHttpRequest. and append fields with FormData Object

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
               var form = $('#forms-items'); //valid form selector
               form.on('submit', function (c) {
                   c.preventDefault();

                   var data = new FormData();
                   $.each($(':input', form ), function(i, fileds){
                       data.append($(fileds).attr('name'), $(fileds).val());
                   });
                   $.each($('input[type=file]',form )[0].files, function (i, file) {
                       data.append(file.name, file);
                   });
                   $.ajax({
                       url: 'ajax/submitform.php',
                       data: data,
                       cache: false,
                       contentType: false,
                       processData: false,
                       type: 'POST',
                       success: function (c) {
                            //code here if you want to show any success message
                           alert(response);
                       }
                   });
                   return false;
               });
           })
</script>
```

**and forcing jQuery not to add a Content-Type header for you, otherwise, the upload file boundary string will be missing from it.**