# Unable to Send Files in PHP AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am unable to send files in PHP AJAX Request:

Form:

```
<form class="frmContact" action="#" method="post">
                  <div class="col-md-6">  
                     <input type="hidden" name="emailTo" id="emailTo" value="example@domain.com">     
                     <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="txtName" id="txtName">
                     <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail">
                     <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="txtSubject" id="txtSubject">

                     <input type="file" placeholder="Text File" name="txtFile" id="txtFile" />

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">  
                     <textarea placeholder="Message" cols="40" rows="10" name="txtText" id="txtText"></textarea>
                     <button class="btnSend" type="button">Send Your Message</button>
                     <span id="spanMessage"></span>
                  </div>
               </form>
```

Ajax Code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "includes/mail.php", // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
        contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
        cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
        processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
        success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {
        console.log(data);
        }
        });
```

PHP Code:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_REQUEST); print_r($_FILES);  die;
```

Console Result:

```
Array
(
)

Array
(
)
```

Using jQuery jQuery v1.11.2

Could you please help me debug the error?

Comment: So, where exactly are you sending files to the server?

Comment: @TobiasKun I am unable to read files. Receiving empty $_FILES

Comment: why don't you use: data:$(form).serialize() instead of data: new FormData(this)?

Comment: You`ve missed 'enctype="multipart/form-data" '  attribute, at <form> tag.

Comment: @AngelM. Tried. Didn't work

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr Didnt work with that too!

Comment: On making request, look in firebug or dev tools network tab, are you passing files to the server?

Comment: Show please where you call ajax request.

Comment: `data: new FormData(this)` this ref would be overwrite inside ajax function params, try to create and append fields `FormData()` outside from `$.ajax` function, see this answer for more details http://stackoverflow.com/a/31001452/926333

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr Yes the request is sent.

Comment: @Girish I am glad that works. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Please add this to the form tag:

```
<form class="frmContact" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: i don't think  the `encytype` attr will matter on appending fields in `FormData()`  class, the file will append without encytype attribute.